# Need DB tech and methodology suggestion on mapping keyword relationships

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database, nosql

I have to spider over 2 million URLs and harvest their meta keywords.
I then need to store each unique keyword and via the DB, keep track of which keyword appears with / is linked to other keywords.

I'm grappling with what DB to use - standard RDBM seems to intensive for this task - my gut tells me that a MongoDB solution might be the way to go ... but I'm very new to it.

Open to all experienced suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nearly an ideal use case for Cassandra.

Indexing URLs by what keywords appear in them is very similar to what Cassandra was originally designed for at Facebook: inbox search.  Using a wide-row format where the row key is a keyword and each column is a URL would work extremely well for mapping keywords to URLs.  To get a reverse mapping of URL to keyword, use the URL as a row key and one column per keyword.

To track first-order relationships between keywords, you can use one row per keyword, and each column in the row can be another keyword that was found at the same URL.  If you want to store more information, such as the number of times the two keywords appeared together, use one of [Cassandra's built-in distributed counters](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-0-8-part-2-counters) for each column value.  They are designed to handle a high volume of increments as well as make it possible to have millions of active, distinct counters.

It sounds like this dataset could become very large.  If so, you should seriously consider using Cassandra in place of MongoDB.  Mongo simply does not handle datasets that are larger than memory very well at all (due to its reliance on mmap), while Cassandra was designed with a strong emphasis on efficiently writing to and reading from larger than memory data sets.

Comment: For MongoDB you need to worry about the INDEX SIZE not the DATASET SIZE.  It handles datasets vastly larger than available RAM.   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexing+Advice+and+FAQ#IndexingAdviceandFAQ-MakesureyourindexescanfitinRAM

Comment: Sure, if you're indexes don't fit in RAM, you're definitely dead in the water (and for this particular use case, the indexes themselves will be quite large).  But having an active dataset that is larger than memory will quickly make you I/O bound, whether you're talking about writes or reads; there will be a lot of page swapping.

Answer (score 1):

This could work well in MongoDB.  You could create a document for each URL.  Have an array object in that document listing the keywords used.  Index on that array so you can quickly find any URL that mentions any specific keyword.

Use Map-Reduce to summarize: use a map that emits every 2-gram (or n-gram) of the keywords used (sort them alphabetically) for each URL and then a reduce to count up the unique combinations.  Dump the result into a new collection and sort by frequency.